# I am getting exception "Could not parse configuration"

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

below are the details of exception I got:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not                              
         parse configuration:<br>
         <br> hibernate.cfg.xml<br><br>
         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1491)
         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1425)
         at com.javatpoint.mypackage.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:14)<br>
         Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException:Read timed out Nested exception: 
         Read timed out<br> <br>
      at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)<br>
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1481)
      <br>
       ... 2 more
```

This is hibernate.hbm.xml I have coded.  I am using MySQL through 
XAMPP as backend. Could you please help to 
solve this? 'hr' is database name which I am using. username is 
root.password is left blank.

```
  <!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
 <hibernate-configuration>  
 <session-factory>  
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>  
<propertyname="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr</property>  
<property name="connection.username">root</property>    
 <property name="connection.password"></property>    
<property 
name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
<mapping resource="employee.hbm.xml"/>  
</session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: I added DTD ...still got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file: a space is missing between the tag name `property` and the attribute name `name`.  Change this line:

```
<propertyname="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr</property>
```

to this:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr</property>
```